# There is no progress in the Xcode archive

Tags: archive

I pressed the archive button to finish building the app and post it to the iTunes Store. But in the Compiling Swift source files, the progress bar has stopped and I am waiting for 13 hours. but builds well on my iPhone or test device. [image: 13 hours this position]

I archived another project that I created earlier. It stopped at a certain point, but the process went well. The only thing I guessed was, is there something wrong with my Mac's RAM? I am currently writing 4 gigabytes,

and while archiving, x-code related programs are using 3.8 gigabytes. Of course, the mouse scrolls or everything else is slow. But obviously in the same condition, the build and archiving of other projects worked well.

xcode version is 8.2.1(8C1002)

Comment: Some details, maybe not important, are needed.  Xcode version, Swift version, EXACT error.... You provided a screenshot that simply cannot help anyone here to help. Last question: Why the Swift tag? It doesn't fit.

Comment: @dfd I got the same problem on archiving my new APP, it did not happened on my previous APPs. xcode 8.2.1, swift 3.0. BTW the APP runs well on simulator and real device.